# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function conexion() PHP y SQLServer

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Estuve como medio día de mi trabajo tratando de solucionar este problema, estoy usando Wamp (Xampp no funcionó correctamente y sigo averiguando el motivo) y necesito hacer una conexión a una BD SQLserver, como wamp no trae una extensión para eso ya la instalé después de buscar mucho y si carga en los mostrados en el icono además de que también se muestra en el info en un navegador, por lo cual si se está cargando, pero estoy tratando de hacer un select con inner join y el archivo que requiero me está mostrando este error que realmente el código creo que no tiene problemas.

```
 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function conexion() in C:\wamp64\www\ruta\del\archivo\que\estoycargando.php on line 3
```

Mas específicamente la linea 3 es esto:

```
<?php
include "conexion_sql.php";
$conexion=conexion();

$sql="SELECT blablablablabla";
```

y el include es este archivo de conexión:

```
<?php
    #ini_set("sqlsrv.charset", "UTF-8");
    $serverName = "0.0.0.0\Servidor,Puerto";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"nombredb", "UID"=>"usuariodb", "PWD"=>"C0ntr4s3ñ4" );
    $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conexion ) {
     echo "";
    }else{
         echo "La Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

Es la primera vez que junto PHP con SQLServer (Siempre era con Mysql o maria o así), así que no se si estoy haciendo algo realmente mal, por lo cual cualquier ayuda / consejo sería muy bien recibida.

Muchas Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Hola, Dante. El error te indica que estás llamando a un método que no existe. ¿Dónde tienes definido ese método? ```(function nombreFuncion)```

Comment: En el archivo del `include` la conexión no se llama desde una función, por tanto esto sobra: `$conexion=conexion();`. Puedes usar `$conexion` directamente porque se crea fuera de funciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es que estas llamando a una funcion que nunca has establecido. Podrias arreglar este error de la siguiente forma:

```
function Conexion_mysql()
{
#ini_set("sqlsrv.charset", "UTF-8");
    $serverName = "0.0.0.0\Servidor,Puerto";
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"nombredb", "UID"=>"usuariodb", "PWD"=>"C0ntr4s3ñ4" );
    $conexion = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conexion ) {
     echo "";
    }else{
         echo "La Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
}
```

Guarda lo anterior en el archivo que estas incluyendo `"conexion_sql.php"` e incluyelo de la misma forma que la anterior. (Te recomiendo que uses parentesis ej: `include ("archivo.php");`

Te quedaría algo asi:

```
<?php
include ("conexion_sql.php");
$conexion=Conexion_mysql();

$sql="SELECT blablablablabla";
```

Comment: Notese que lo que hice fue añadir una funcion que englobe al query que estas haciendo. De esta forma lo puedes invocar dentro de tu otro archivo.

Comment: No se debería mostrar errores internos, como haces con `sqlsrv_errors()` por ejemplo, es información que los hackers explotan para atacar el sistema.

Comment: Solo estoy reutilizando su codigo. Quise arreglar el error de la variable no definida. Pero es cierto, no se deben mostrar errores internos

Comment: Muchas gracias!, el error es super simple... no se me ocurrió la verdad lo de la función, pero bueno...

Gracias!

Comment: No hay por que! Suerte y a no rendirse!